# ISAPI Rewrite Syntax Incorrect?

Tags: isapi-rewrite

I'm trying to use Helicon Isapi rewrite on IIS 6.  Basically all I want to accomplish is redirecting a directory to another site.

I would like to the URL to stay the same.

The URL is http://www.harrisburgu.edu/online-graduate-degrees

```
http://166.78.104.118/online-graduate-degree
```

Here is my syntax that dos not seem to work, I've placed the file in the root of my virtual host or should I place it in the folder online-graduate-degrees?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^harrisburgu\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^online-graduate-degrees$ http:\\166.78.104.118/online-graduate-degree    [NC,P,L]
```

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Mr.brandt, you're all over internet. And I'm folowing you ))) Let's continue looking at your logs here - http://www.helicontech.com/community/viewtopic.php?t=2277